# How to create JSON array from SQL rows in C# (Azure Function)

Tags: c#, json, .net, azure-functions

I am building an API pulling data from Azure SQL would like to create a JSON array.

Currently I have an Azure Function written in C#.

Sample data looks like this:
[image: SQL data]

I would like the output to look like this

[image]

My Azure Function is working fine, I just need to create an array. (I think)

```
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            SqlDataReader dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

            var r = Serialize(dataReader);
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(r, Formatting.Indented);
```

I'm new to .NET and not sure quite where to begin. Thanks!

Comment: What does your current result (`json` variable) look like? What does `Serialize()` do? What's the type of `r`?

Comment: "My Azure Function is working fine" Where is this function and what is an output data? And pls replace all images by text if you want some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it this way. Read the data into a Type that you can then use LINQ on to group into the desired shape, then serialize to JSON.

```
//Start with a list of the raw data by reading the rows into CardData list
List<CardData> cards = new List<CardData>();

while (dataReader.Read())
{
    //You should check for DBNull, this example not doing that
    cards.Add(new CardData
    {
        card_key = dataReader.GetString(0),
        card_name = dataReader.GetString(1),
        card_network = dataReader.GetString(2),
        annual_fee = dataReader.GetDecimal(3),
        speed_bonus_category = dataReader.GetString(4),
        speed_bonus_amount = dataReader.GetInt32(5)
    });
}

//Now transform the data into an object graph that will serialize 
//to json the way you want. (flattens the redundant data)

var grp = cards.GroupBy(x => new { x.card_key, x.card_name, x.card_network, x.annual_fee });

var groupedData = new List<CardsModel>();

groupedData = grp.Select(g => new CardsModel
{
    card_key = g.Key.card_key,
    card_name = g.Key.card_name,
    card_network = g.Key.card_network,
    annual_fee = g.Key.annual_fee,
    Bonuses = g.Select(b => new SpeedBonus
    {
        SpeedBonusCategory = b.speed_bonus_category,
        SpeedBonusAmount = b.speed_bonus_amount
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();

//Finally you can serialize
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupedData, Formatting.Indented);
```

Here are the supporting classes you could use:

```
//represents the non-redundant object graph
public class CardsModel
{
    public string card_key { get; set; }
    public string card_name { get; set; }
    public string card_network { get; set; }
    public decimal annual_fee { get; set; }
    public List<SpeedBonus> Bonuses { get; set; }
}

public class SpeedBonus
{
    public string SpeedBonusCategory { get; set; }
    public int SpeedBonusAmount { get; set; }
}

//represents raw data, has redundant cc info
public class CardData
{
    public string card_key { get; set; }
    public string card_name { get; set; }
    public string card_network { get; set; }
    public decimal annual_fee { get; set; }
    public string speed_bonus_category { get; set; }
    public int speed_bonus_amount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: that's great! took me eight minutes to implement!